# What is the best practice for delete data from database table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rdbms

In my case I want to maintain a table for store some kind of data and after some period remove from the first table and store to another table.

I want to clarify the what is the best practice in this kind of scenario. 
I am using MySql database in java base application.

Comment: It all depends the scenario. GIve us some more information about how much data, how often, how the indexing is likely to be affected etc.

Comment: If you're archiving data, then you may want to remove it from your DB entirely after archiving it, rather than "moving it to another table"

Comment: @Preet Both of table have may have thousand of data row. actually what i want is, after some business process remove data from first table and add to a another table. I want to clarify in removing part. What is the best way to do it and do i have to worry about primary key (auto increment) of first table. Because again it fill with new set of data.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, I follow this procedure. Incase I want to delete a row. I have a `tinyint` column called `deleted`. I mark this column for that row as `true`.

That indicates that that row has been marked as deleted, So I dont, pick it up.

Later (maybe once a day), I run a script which in a single shot either delete the rows entirely or migrate them to another table... etc.

This is useful as every time you delete a row (even if it's 1 row), mysql has to reindex (it's indexes). This might require significant system resources depending on your data size or number of indexes. You might not want to incur these overheads everytime...

Comment: Add a view to select only the active records that is what the application uses to display data. That way you won't forget and show the deleted records before they are physically deleted or moved to an archive table.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information but I think if both tables have same data structure then you can avoid using two tables. Just add another column in first table and set **status/type** for those particular second table records.

**For Example:**

```
id | Name | BirthDate  |    type
------------------------------------
 1 | ABC  | 01-10-2001 | firsttable
 2 | XYZ  | 01-01-2000 | secondtable
```

You can pick records like this:

```
select * from tablename where type='firsttable'
```

OR

```
select * from tablename where type='secondtable'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are archiving old data, there should be a way to set up a scheduled job in mysql. I know there is in SQL Server and it's the kind of function that most databases require, so I imagine it can be done in mySQL. Shecdule the job to run in the low-usage hours. Have it select all records more than a year old (or whatever amount of time of records you want to keep active) and move them to an archive table and then delete them. Depending on the number of records you would be moving, it might be best to do this once a week or daily. You don't want the number of records expiring to be so large it affects performance greatly or makes the job take too long.

Inarchiving, the critical piece is to make sure you keep all the records that will be needed frequently and don't forget to consider reporting in that(many reports need to havea years worth or two years worth of data, do not archive records these reports should need). Then you also need to set up a way for users to access the archived records on the rare occasions they may need to see them.